# How to translate month names in "Archives"

Tags: customization, sidebar, archives, translation

How can I modify month names in "Archives" in my blog? I would like to translate english month names into my mother tongue. I'm using the english version of wordpress 3.1.3

Comment: How do you show the month's name in the "Archives" page?

Comment: May 2011, June 2011 etc. Just like e.g in this blog: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/

Comment: No, I meant which code are you using to show month's name, not how they're shown :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if the translation is only for the archive widget, a filter function might work (to be added to functions.php of the theme):

```
add_filter('get_archives_link', 'translate_archive_month');

function translate_archive_month($list) {
  $patterns = array(
    '/January/', '/February/', '/March/', '/April/', '/May/', '/June/',
    '/July/', '/August/', '/September/', '/October/',  '/November/', '/December/'
  );
  $replacements = array(
    'jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 
    'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'
  );    
  $list = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $list);
return $list; 
}
```

Comment: Great, works really well!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your theme, but some language strings may be coded in the archives.php file. Check that and also see http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [WordPress Multilingual](http://wpml.org/) plugin will do this, though I have not used it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to change the whole language of my blog, just those month names.

Answer (score 0):

I made a function in 'functions.php':

```
function mes($month) {
switch ($month) {
case 1:
    $m_es = "ene";
    break;
case 2:
    $m_es = "feb";
    break;
case 3:
    $m_es = "mar";
    break;
case 4:
    $m_es = "abr";
    break;
case 5:
    $m_es = "may";
    break;
case 6:
    $m_es = "jun";
    break;
case 7:
    $m_es = "jul";
    break;
case 8:
    $m_es = "ago";
    break;
case 9:
    $m_es = "sep";
    break;
case 10:
    $m_es = "oct";
    break;
case 11:
    $m_es = "nov";
    break;
case 12:
    $m_es = "dic";
    break;
}
return($m_es); }
```

Assigning every numeric value of the months to the translation I would like to show.

Then on my 'single.php' I just gave it some format:

```
<?php echo get_the_date('d') . '.' . mes(get_the_date('n')) . '.' . get_the_date('y'); ?>
```

It's worked for me.

Saludos!

Comment: Just for your information: You can save yourself some code/effort and directly return the string for each case, meaning: `case 1: return "ene"; case 2: return "feb"; ...`. That way you don't need any variable, don't need to instantiate, don't need any `break;`, and thus have less code.